# DM Admin members on member join discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

So I am playing around with coding a bot, but am a complete newb to coding. I want the bot to DM all members of the Admin role when someone joins the server. I have looked everywhere and cannot get my head around it. I have tried multiple ways with no success. Has anyone get any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to loop through everyone on the server and check if they are an administrator

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    server = member.server
    for user in server.members:
        if user.server_permissions.administrator:
            await client.send_message(user, "A new member has joined")

client.run('token')
```

Comment: You could also do `from discord.ext.commands import Bot` instead of `import discord`,  `bot = Bot(command_prefix="<prefix>")` instead of `client = discord.Client()`, and replace any `client.` with `bot.`. This will make it easier to make commands later on, which is why I would recommend that instead.